# ArrayList Based Binary Tree - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree

I am currently in the process of implementing an `ArrayList` based `binary tree in Java`.  I am trying to figure out how this would be done, but I am running into a wall. There are a bunch of `methods` in a `class` I am supposed to implement, but each time I try something, it doesn't seem to work.

We have `Position objects` that are identified by `Position<E>`.  In this `class` we have an `array list` that is `private`, and a `root variable`, both `accessible` only by this `class`, so the `size()` `method`, and the `isEmpty()` methods are simple.  However, I am running into some trouble when it comes to implementing the methods such as: `hasLeft(Position<E>)`, `hasRight(Position<E>)` `left(Position<E>), right(Position<E>),` `addRoot(E e)`, etc... The Left and Right methods simply return the `left child` and `right child of a node`.  I am familiar with `ArrayList`, but not when it comes to implementing a `binary tree class` with them.

How would I go about implementing these methods?  I am stuck, and I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the `interface` you are supposed to implement?

Comment: It is simply

public interface Position<E> {
E element();
}

Answer (score 2):

When you write binary trees as an Array you are building what's typically called a heap.  Heaps are fairly well documented and this article will give you lots of detail about how they are implemented:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

Answer (score 0):

You can build a binary tree on the top of a contiguous array. Basically, having a 0 based index, for an element on the i th position of the array:

```
left(i) : 2 * i + 1
right(i) : 2 * i + 2
```